# iOS - how can I add audio files into another audio file?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I want to add some can music or sound effect into an audio that recorded using avaudiorecorder. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Audio mixing can be really challenging.  You need to mix the two waveforms-- combine the data programatically.

[Here is a nice little demo](http://atastypixel.com/blog/how-to-mix-audio-samples-properly-on-ios/) showing one way to do so.

And [here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11397971/793607) with some ideas.

[and another sample](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex4).

Sorry for all the links, but this is a pretty complicated question.

Comment: thanks for the useful reference, @HalR. I am wondering if ios sdk allows me to play two audios simultaneously? So may be I can play one audio first, and at certain time, I play another audio. Hm, will this work?

Comment: and by the way, @HalR do you know how to cut audio and append other audio to it? can you give me some guides or ref. links? thanks. What I am trying to do is cut A into A' and A'', and then add B in between them and output them as one audio (A'+B+A'').

Comment: Oh sure.  I played multiple sounds at once in my games on the iOS.  There are a few good ways of doing it.  But here is a link for one of them:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14830109/793607  If you want to get extreme, you can even find code out there to help you place sounds in 3D (left right channels, etc).

Comment: @Newbie That is a non-trivial issue, that will take some significant effort.  Hopefully you can find some source code to start with.